# MS Word cannot add to reference

Tags: c#, ms-word

I need to make some application to work with MS Word. I read some instruction and there was told, that I need to add Reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. When I opened context menu add reference - I haven't find it there. What should I do?

MS Visual Studio 2012, Windows 7.

Maybe somebody can give me more newer instructions how to program for MS Word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not install the Primary Interop Assemblies when you installed word, that is why `Microsoft.Office.*` is missing.

Follow [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw.aspx) on how to install the assemblies.

> To install the PIAs when you install Office
>
> 1. Ensure that you have a version of the .NET Framework that is no older than 2.0.
> 2. Install Microsoft Office and make sure that the **.NET Programmability Support** feature is selected for the applications you
>    want to extend (this feature is included in the default installation).
>
> To install the PIAs by using the redistributable package
>
> 1. Ensure that you have a version of the .NET Framework that is no older than 2.0.
> 2. Download the PIAs for Microsoft Office 2010 from the following page on the Microsoft website: [Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable.](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166026)
> 3. Install the PIAs by following the instructions on the download page.

Answer (score 0):

Assemblies > Extensions

and select both the extensions and just click OK and you are done

[image]

Comment: khm.. really strange, because I havent ANY Microsoft.office.* references

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that word is installed as well.  The interop libraries are installed when word is installed.  If you cannot find them in the reference, but have word installed, then you can download and find them [here for 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508), or [here for 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18346)

Comment: I have downloaded for 2010, double-click on o2010pia.msi, some window shows for a moment and then - NOTHING (((

Comment: Is word 2010 installed on your machine?